# How to link 2 list workflows together?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, designer-workflow

For example, I have 2 lists - A and B.
Suppose after the workflow in List A is done, I want to trigger the workflow in List B to happen. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**By default,** the workflow is triggered in the following cases,

- Item Created,
- Item Changed,
- Or Manually,

[image]

So as a workaround, at the end of the first workflow for List A, you can update a specific related field item with its **same** value in the List B, in this case, the List B workflow will be triggered on item changed event!

**Also,** In SharePoint workflow 2013, There is an action called "`Start a List Workflow`" that can be used to trigger another workflow from the first workflow.

[image]

> **Note:** The `Start a List Workflow` action only run the SharePoint 2010 workflow, that can't be added in `App step` in SharePoint Workflow 2013.